# Java to c# conversion for making a androidstudio app in xamarin

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

The below line perfectly works in Java (AndroidStudio), but it is returning errors in c# (Xamarin). Don't know what is going wrong. I'm new to C#

```
private final int NONE = -1, TOUCH_TOP_FIRST = 0, TOUCH_TOP_SECOND = 1, TOUCH_BOT_THIRD = 2, TOUCH_BOT_FOURTH = 3;
int currentTouch = NONE;
```

At line `currentTouch = NONE;`

> error: A field initialiser cannot reference the non-static field,method or property CameraPreview.NONE

Comment: int currentTouch = -1; that's what you need to do

Comment: cant i give NONE to the currenttouch?

Answer (score 1):

> The below line perfectly works in Java (AndroidStudio), but it is returning errors in c# (Xamarin). Don't know what is going wrong. I'm new to C#

`final` keyword is just for java, in C# you can use [`readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) .

If you are new to C#, I suggest you quickly go through the language tutorial: [C# Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/index) as the first step.

Then you can learn the differences between Android App(Java) and Android App(Xamarin)  through [Xamarin for Java Developers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/xamarin-for-java/)

Comment: i have removed final..Even then —> int CurrentTouch = NONE; is returning error